# inverse of $y=\frac{x}{\log{x}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, inverse-function

> **By Prime Number theorem** $\pi(x)=\frac{x}{\log{x}}$ **for large x**

Putting $x=p_n$ where $p_n$ denotes $n^{th}$ prime number,
We have, $\pi(p_n)=\frac{p_n}{\log{p_n}}$,
$\because \pi(p_n)=n$,
$\therefore \frac{p_n}{\log{p_n}}=n$,
$\therefore p_n=\pi^{-1}(n)$,
Thus, finding inverse of $y=\frac{x}{\log{x}}$ would help us to find $n^{th}$ prime number for large $n$
Please provide clues to find it?

Comment: Since this cannot be done in elementary way, a special function called Lambert W-function is introduced for this kind of needs.

Comment: @Randall oh no!

Comment: Well, it's not fatal:  it is invertible for a generous range of positive $x$s (very likely $x >e$), which is all you need anyway.  (Hence my deletion, since my comment is a bit irrelevant.)

Comment: @Randall then what is th inverse?

Comment: Oh, I didn't say you could write it down in closed form.  Just as if I asked you for the inverse of $\sin x$ on a suitable domain, you can't say anything better than $\arcsin x$.

Comment: @Randall so is it possible to solve $5=\frac{x}{\log{x}}$ for $x$ manually?

Comment: The Prime Number Theorem does *not* say $\pi(x) = \frac{x}{\log x}$ for large $x$; it only says their ratio approaches $1$.  Their difference can be arbitrarily large.  See OEIS sequence [A057835](https://oeis.org/A057835).

Comment: @mathaholic  In closed form without a decimal approximation?  I doubt it.

Comment: @Randall is there  a better wy for a computer to do it instead of checking all values of x

Comment: We can write $$ x = \frac{W_{-1}(-1/y)}{-1/y} $$ for the Lambert W-function with the branch-cut indexed by $-1$. Since this function is relatively well-studied, including asymptotic expansion as $y\to\infty$ and so forth, it is slightly better than mere tautology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about prime numbers, but the easiest way to find the inverse is usually to use substitution:

$$\pi(x)=\frac{x}{\log{x}}\land u=\pi^{-1}(x)\implies x=\frac{u}{\log{u}}$$

$$\implies x\log{u}=u\implies u^x=e^u\implies u=-xW_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

(there's a step between $u^x=e^u$ and $u=-xW(-1/x)$ that I skipped, but I would never do it by hand anyway.)

Where $W$ is the product-logarithm or Lambert W function, as it is also called. $W$ and $W_{-1}$ are both built into Wolfram Alpha, so for particular values, I would just enter it there.

You can input it as -x ProductLog(-1,-1/x).

Comment: Just a nitpicking: The standard branch cut, i.e. $W = W_0$, is not adequate for OP's question since $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{W(-1/x)}{-1/x} = 1.$$ You may want to use the other branch cut $W_{-1}$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Fair enough. Normally I would just treat everything as set-valued and call it a day.

Answer (score 3):

An asymptotically correct inverse of $\frac{x}{\log x}$ is $x \log x$.  It has been shown by Rosser that $n\log n$ is always an underestimate for the $n$th prime.  Better estimates, due to Rosser and Dusart, show that the $n$th prime lies between
$$
n(\log n + \log\log n - 1)
$$
and
$$
n(\log n + \log\log n)
$$
for all $n\ge 6$.

For example, taking $n = 10^6$, this shows that the millionth prime is between $15441302$ and $16441302$.  In fact, it is nearer the lower value: $p_{1000000} = 15485863$.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the solution of $y=x/\log(x)$ in terms of the Lambert $W$ function, you can also solve it numerically by the simple iterative procedure

$$ x_{n}= y \log(x_{n-1})$$

with $x_0 = y \log(y)$. It converges fast, especially for large $n$.